# Mocking a stateless session bean gives javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, mocking, singleton, mockito

There is some class:

```
 @Stateless   
 public class SomeSimpleBean implements SomeSimpleLocal{

    private static SomeSimpleBean cachedInstance;

    public static SomeSimpleLocal lookup() throws NamingException {
      if (cachedInstance == null) {
        cachedInstance = (SomeSimpleLocal) new InitialContext()
            .lookup(“something”);
    }
    return cachedInstance;
 }
 ...
}
```

and there is another class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass(){

private SomeSimpleLocal getSomeSimpleBean() throws SomeException {

    try {
        return SomeSimpleLocal.lookup();
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new SomeException(“…”, e);
      }
    }

private String generateResponse(String transactionId, String someParameter) throws Exception {

    SomeSimpleBean beanController = getSomeSimpleBean();

    String receivedString = controller.someMethod(transactionId,
        someParameter);
    return receivedString;
    }
    ...

public String giveMeSomeData(){
    ...
  String xxx = generateResponse(a,b);
    ...
    return someString;
   }
 }
```

Is it possible to mock `SomeSimpleBean` in this case? Mocking `SomeSimpleBean` gives `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException`.

Comment: Please show us the code of your test where you try and mock the bean. Also, please try to use *real* code. This doesn't compile, for example: `public class SomeOtherClass(){`. Finally, please indent your code neatly so we can read it more easily.

Comment: Solved. Mocked InitialContextFactoryBuilder, and then called
NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(builder); It works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

InitialContextFactory fact = mock(InitialContextFactory.class);
InitialContextFactoryBuilder builder = mock(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.class);
InitialContext ctx = mock(InitialContext.class);
SomeSimpleBean someSimepleBeanMock = mock(SomeSimpleBean.class);

NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(builder);

when(builder.createInitialContextFactory(env)).thenReturn(fact);
when(NamingManager.getInitialContext(env)).thenReturn(ctx);

when(ctx.lookup("SomeSimpleBean/local")).thenReturn(
        someSimpleBeanMock);
```